# gnatpp ceases working after a while

Tags: ada, gnat

I'm on a mac, and I format my files with "gnatpp  -rnb *.ads *adb" and it refuses to format some files. When I create a new file it works, and after a while, when the file grow/age (I couldn't find a pattern), it stops working. It spits the same file as the input, event when I try with -pipe.

What's happening? is there a limit that I would be reaching somewhere? I can't find anything relevant in the help and I have no error relevant error message. The files are all less than 200 lines long.

there is no error message:

```
maquette:src nraynaud$ gnatpp -w -v -rnb -M150 *.ads
gnatpp 4.9.0
Copyright 2003-2014, AdaCore.
TMPDIR = "/private/var/folders/rb/4gj9qf4j4_765mm9dlfmd0k00000gn/T"
[13] button.ads
[12] driver.ads
[11] last_chance_handler.ads
[10] leds.ads
[9] motor.ads
[8] registers.ads
[7] stm32f4-busses.ads
[6] stm32f4-genericperipheral.ads
[5] stm32f4-gpio.ads
[4] stm32f4-reset_clock_control.ads
[3] stm32f4-sysconfig_control.ads
[2] stm32f4-tim.ads
[1] stm32f4.ads
```

Comment: Is there any way you could post one of the cursed files? (preferably with enough context that it will at least compile).

Comment: yes, here : https://github.com/nraynaud/bldc_ada for example stm32f4.ads is cursed for me. If I add some tabs at the beginning of a line and then execute "gnatpp -w -v -rnb -M150 src/stm32f4.ads", it doesn't re-format the tab. thanks for your interest, not having a formater is really painful.

Answer (score 2):

gnatpp complains that your file does not compile, which is required for gnatpp to work.
From the GNAT User's Guide:

> To produce a reformatted file, gnatpp generates and uses the ASIS tree for the input source and thus requires the input to be syntactically and semantically legal. If this condition is not met, gnatpp will terminate with an error message; no output file will be generated.

Comment: Well actually, when I force it to avoid the error file, it still doesn't format my other cursed files.

Comment: Try with Verbose mode (-v) and Warning mode (-w)

Comment: good call, thanks, this stupid program doesn't format anything in the file if one line is too long. I don't seem to find how to make it wrap the line.

Comment: actually my file is still cursed if a line is longer than 79 char, also I use gnatpp -w -v -rnb -M150 *.ads . No waring or message this time.